# Show string arrays in listview

Tags: arrays, listview

I'm trying to make an app whoes purpose is to show string arrays in a listview.
I have an XML file stored in the res/values folder whitch contains several string arrays, the arrays are named *list1, list2, list3 etc*.
Now, I want to show the arrays one by one by cliking a "Next" button in my UI.
I want the "Next" button to clear the current array and load the next one.
Can anyone help?